# Why nuget tries to look for `dll` file on Linux

Tags: c#, mono, package, nuget

I am working on Debian Stable Linux and installing packages using `nuget`. However, sometimes I get error message where nuget is not able to find a `dll` file. For example:

```
$ nuget install Accord.Math
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Accord (≥ 3.8.0)'.
Installing 'Accord.Math 3.8.0'.
Could not find a part of the path "/tmp/nuget/sh5gjtik.wke/lib/netstandard2.0/Accord.Math.dll".
```

Since dll is a windows file, I am not able to understand why nuget is looking for them on Linux.

Also, how can this problem be solved?

Comment: .dll is just an extension, not a guarantee of what's inside. Both native Win32 libraries and .NET assemblies use the same extension. The latter works just fine under Mono, assuming it doesn't use any Windows-only features.

Comment: Why this error and how can it be corrected?

Comment: You already asked that. If I had an answer for your specific error, I would have posted one. My comment was only pointing out that your premise, "dll is a windows file" is incorrect, in the hope that that might help you avoid barking up the wrong tree thinking nuget was trying to install Windows software when it wasn't.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using `nuget install`? That's not how to add a NuGet reference to a project. If you're using .NET Core you should use `dotnet add package Accord.Math`, or just edit the csproj with a text editor. I don't know about Mono, but `nuget install` still doesn't make it part of the project.